# Alternative Open Source software to GFI end point security

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation, security, alternative

What are the GUI open source alternatives To GFI end point security for Windows?

knowing that I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 64bit

Thanks in advance...

Comment: this is not open source..... commercial stuff.
anyone succeed to set a station doing the same job as gfi for free using ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Try Endpoint Protecter. According to their website:

The Endpoint Protector 4 Web administration and reporting console offers you a complete overview of the device activity on your computers, whether you work with Windows, Mac or Linux platforms. You will be able to define access policies per user/computer/device and authorize devices for certain user or user groups. Thus, your company will stay productive while maintaining control over the device fleet use.

http://www.endpointprotector.com/products/endpoint_protector#1

Comment: Endpoint Protector consist of 4 main parts: Device Control - Content Aware Protection - Mobile Device Management - Virtual/Hardware Appliance... Only the device control is compatible with linux... Also it's not Free and NOT OPEN SOURCE

Comment: Is there any Open source solution to replace GFI EndpointSecurity